# Get Requested middleware list from $request?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-fortify

In my project created with Laravel 8 with vue+ inertia + fortify package, I use two guards one for normal users and one for admins. but there only have one login view redirect.

I just want to show different login to normal users and another login to admins. it should detect by middleware used in the route. I can filter it, if I can get the requested guard name from there.

Here is my example route:

```
<?php
//'auth:users' is normal users guard

 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:users'], function () {
            Route::prefix('/account')->name('account.')->group(function () {
                Route::get('/', [AccountController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
});});

//'auth:web' is admin users guard

 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:web'], function () {
      Route::prefix('/admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
            Route::prefix('/account')->name('account.')->group(function () {
                Route::get('/', [AdminAccountController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
   });
 });
});
```

auth middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        // both request coming to here i want get middlware name from here
   //       if('auth:web'){
 //redirect to adimin login
 //         }else{
 //redirect to userlogin
 //}

       
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('admin.login');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all middleware used for the current route using `request()->route()->computedMiddleware` so your code would be:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if ($request->route() && in_array('auth:web', $request->route()->computedMiddleware??[]) {
         // redirect to admin login
       } else {
         // redirect to admin login
       }
 
       
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('admin.login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `computedMiddleware` is usefull thank you very much!